# Format an Unsigned Byte to a Three ASCII Digits

Tags: formatting, integer, assembly

I'm working on a game for the Atari VCS and have been dusting off my 30+ year old skills in writing MOS 6502 assembly language.

The VCS runs at 1.19 MHz and is based on a MOS 6507 chip with some custom logic and 128 bytes only of RAM.

**Outline of Problem**

The game needs to display a value as 3 ASCII digits, but I'm working in full range signed and unsigned bytes, rather than BCD, so I now have the problem of converting from a full range byte to ASCII digits.

**What I have so Far**

I have been able to put the following together, and it appears to work. I'd welcome any tips for making it smaller, faster etc.

Currently the program is estimated to run in around 114+ cycles, just counting the instruction cycle counts with no branches taken.

```
;
; FormatUnsigned.asm
;
; 6502 routine to format an unsigned byte into a space
; followed by 2 decimal digits if < 100, or 3 decimal
; digits if >= 100.
;

        seg.u Variables
        org $80

char1   .byte                   ; output chars
char2   .byte
char3   .byte
Temp    .byte                   ; temp


        seg Code
        org $f000

TestFormat
        lda #211                ; sample value
        jsr FormatUnsigned      ; format
        brk                     ; halt

; A = value to format unsigned
FormatUnsigned:
        ldy #$20                ; default hundreds digit
        sty char1               ; is a space
; calculate char1
        ldy #$30                ; '0'
        sec                     ; set carry for sub loop
Sub100
        sbc #100
        iny                     ; y = '1', '2'
        bcs Sub100              ; loop whilst carry is not borrowed
        adc #100                ; add 100 back
        dey                     ; and take back the inc to y
        cpy #$30                ; if y is '0', just leave the space in there
        beq SkipHundreds
        sty char1               ; save '1' or '2' into char1
SkipHundreds
; format value < 100 into BCD
        tay                     ; save a in y
        lsr
        lsr
        lsr
        lsr
        and #$F                 ; get high nybble
        tax                     ; into x for indexing
        lda highNybble,x
        sta Temp                ; save in temp

        tya                     ; get value - 100s back
        and #$0f                ; low nybble
        tay                     ; low nybble in y
        cmp #$0a                ; <10?
        bcc NoSub10

        sbc #$0a                ; subtract 10
        tay                     ; save in y
        clc                     
        lda #$10                ; Add '10' to bcd saved value
        adc Temp
        sta Temp
        tya
NoSub10
        sed                     ; decimal mode
        adc Temp                ; add bcd value to 0-9 in a
        sta Temp                ; save bcd value
        cld                     ; leave decimal mode

Write2ndChar
        lsr                     ; get high nybble
        lsr
        lsr
        lsr
        and #$0f
        adc #$30
        sta char2               ; save 2nd character

Write3rdChar
        lda Temp
        and #$0f                ; get low nybble
        adc #$30
        sta char3               ; save 3rd character
        rts


highNybble
        .byte $00
        .byte $16
        .byte $32
        .byte $48
        .byte $64
        .byte $80
        .byte $96
```

The program works correctly for tested inputs, producing an output of $32 $31 $31 for the decimal value 211.

Answer (score 3):

### First observations.

- Memory access is costly in terms of cycles. Your solution uses 10 of these. The program I present later on manages to just require 3 accesses to memory.
- By placing the most used variables in the zero-page, you obtained the best possible memory access performance, but avoiding variables is preferable.
- The *FormatUnsigned* subroutine uses some 76 bytes and the byte-variables add another 11 bytes. This is a lot for such an humble task. The routine I present later on will be written in <strike>46</strike> 43 bytes and only add 3 byte-variables.

---

### An opportunity for optimizing.

> ```
> lsr
> lsr
> lsr
> lsr
> and #$F                 ; get high nybble
> ```

You don't need the `and #$0F` instruction because the 4 `lsr` instructions in a row already leave the high nibble empty. This shaves off 2 bytes from the program and reduces the number of cycles by 2. These benefits double because you used this construct twice throughout the program.

---

### A unclear comment.

> ```
> ; 6502 routine to format an unsigned byte into a space
> ; followed by 2 decimal digits if < 100, or 3 decimal
> ; digits if >= 100.
> ```

From this comment I understand that numbers in the range [0,9] will be shown with 1 leading space and 1 leading zero. Wouldn't you agree this to be ugly?
The version I propose next will show 2 leading spaces on such numbers.

---

### My version.

The worst case runs in 108 cycles. This happens with values from 190 to 199.
The best case for this code runs in just 44 cycles. Not surprisingly this is for inputs from 0 to 9.
I personally don't like the decimal mode of the 6502 and so this solution doesn't use it.

```
    ldx #$20    ;" "
    sec
    sbc #100
    bcc OK1
    ldx #$31    ;"1"
    sbc #100    ;           (1)
    bcc OK1
    inx         ;"2"
    sbc #100    ;           (2)
OK1
    adc #100
    stx char1

    ldy #$2F    ;"0"-1      (4)
    sec
Sub10
    sbc #10     ;           (3)
    iny         ;["0","9"]  (4)
    bcs Sub10
    adc #10
    cpy #$30    ;"0"
    bne OK2
    cpx #$20    ;" "        (5)
    bne OK2     ;           (5)
    ldy #$20    ;" "
OK2
    sty char2

    ora #$30    ;["0","9"]  (6)
    sta char3
```

- (1)(2)(3) The carry flag is already set. No need to use `sec` before `sbc`.
- (2) This instruction is meant to be a jump over the following `adc #100`. This would have required 3 bytes using `jmp STXCHAR1` or 2 bytes using `bcs STXCHAR1`. In both cases it would also have taken 3 cycles to run. By writing a complementary subtraction I undo the effect of the following addition, and realise the shortest code and the least cycles!
- (4) The peculiar value $2F is correct because the loop at *Sub10* always runs at least once the `iny` instruction. Therefore 1 to 10 iterations of this loop will yield Y-register values from $30 to $39.
- (5) This extra code takes care of the 2 leading spaces on numbers from 0 to 9.
- (6) Normally here we would like to add 48 to the value in the accumulator holding [0,9]. Using the `adc #48` instruction would have required a `clc` to give correct result. By using the `ora #48` the result is equally correct but the code is 1 byte smaller and 2 cycles faster.

---

### Still room for improvements.

In an effort to get rid of the separate `sec` instruction I came up with a 1 byte smaller solution. This also no longer contains the complementary `adc #100` that you commented about.

```
    ldx #$20    ;" "
    cmp #100
    bcc OK1
    sbc #100
    ldx #$31    ;"1"
    cmp #100
    bcc OK1
    sbc #100
    inx         ;"2"
OK1
    stx char1
```

Nice, but wouldn't it be possible to combine a few things (the first `sbc #100` and the second `cmp #100`)? Yes. Using `sbc #200` and a conditional complementary `adc #100` the code has yet again shrunk, this time by another 2 bytes.

```
    ldx #$20    ;" "
    cmp #100
    bcc OK1
    ldx #$32    ;"2"
    sbc #200
    bcs OK1
    adc #100
    dex         ;"1"
OK1
    stx char1
```

---

### Some speed measurements.

All of these numbers relate to the first part of the program where the hundreds digit gets calculated.

```
 Input    Question  Answer1  Answer2  Answer3
-------   --------  -------  -------  -------
  0- 99     24        14       10       10      cycles
100-199     33        20       18       19      cycles
200-255     40        23       21       16      cycles
-------   --------  -------  -------  -------
Average    31.02     18.31    15.53    14.83    cycles
           21        20       19       17       bytes
```

For the average it is understood that all numbers from 0 to 255 have the same probability.

Comment: Thanks for that. Some good points, the most basic of which I'd already managed to hit, including the 'optimizing for carry flag state'. You have carried over the adc #100. In fact, there's a shorter solution avoiding adding back the 100 deducted.
I will return with some changes.
Thanks, Jonathan

Comment: You must have read my mind! Early this week I came up with a new solution that's both shorter and faster. Today I've added it to my answer.